# Network problem in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, lubuntu

I am not able to connect internet through USB tethering and wifi. Also in my Ubuntu settings in network options no wire options showing. So I am not able install and open browser without internet in ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Try a different ethernet cable. They go bad.

Comment: Different cable is also not working